# Parsing digits and decimals out of string with re

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string that looks like this:

'Home Cookie viewed item "yada_yada.mov" (22.4338.241384081)'

I need to parse the last set of numbers, the ones between the last period and the closing paren (in this case, 241384081) out of the string, keeping in mind that there may be one or more sets of parenthesis in the filename "yada_yada.mov."

So far I have this:

```
mo = re.match('.*([0-9])\)$', data1)
```

...where data1 is the string. But that is only returning the very last digit.

Any help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: `re.sub(".*[.](.*)\).*","\\1",a)` do you need all the numbers or the numbers just after the second decimal point?  `re.findall(r"\d+(?=\))",a)`? or do you need the whole numbers?`re.sub(".*?(\\d.*)\\).*","\\1",a)`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\d[\d.]*)\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E4E9n8/1).

**Details**

- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Capturing group 1: a digit and then any amount of `.` and digits, 0 or more times
- `\)` - a `)`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/B9Py5g):

```
import re

s='Home Cookie viewed item "yada_yada.mov" (22.4338.241384081)'
m = re.search(r'(\d[\d.]*)\)$', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => 22.4338.241384081
  # print(m.group(1).replace(".", "")) # => 224338241384081
```

Alternative patterns:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\)$    # To match digits and then 0 or more repetitions of . + digits
(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\)\s*$ # To allow any 0+ trailing whitespaces
```